# Preserving or Hiding identity on online fora

Tags: privacy

I post to several fora with different user names. Mainly technical stuff. Is there any benefit to keeping these identities separate using different user names? In that case, is it possible to track me down using my writing patterns, word counts, spelling errors?

Secondly, if there is a benefit to linking all these user names accounts to my linked in profile, for example, what sort of things shoudl I avoid - I have asked a few foolish questions in my day and not sure it will affect my future employment prospects.

Comment: I'm confused. Why would you link your accounts  to your Linkedin profile if you don't want to be tracked down?

Comment: I think this question is not useful at all for anybody.

Comment: @A.Darwin he fears the accounts being tied to his public profile, it's not something he's planning on doing himself

Comment: I think this question would be best answered by looking at articles on how professionals should  maintain online presence. There are also a few articles that have turned up in my search engine since the last search :) .

Comment: Identifying users from "Time Prints" https://security-informatics.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s13388-015-0022-z,   Identifying people from their writing style: https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2013/01/identifying_peo_3.html,  also http://www.darkreading.com/risk-management/how-anonymous-are-your-online-posts/d/d-id/1102966? "In one experiment, researchers were able to identify 80% of users with a 5,000-word writing sample."

Answer (score 1):

I do find your question a bit non-specific.
But here's an educated guess:

> is it possible to track me down using my writing patterns etc. ?

This is probably possible but would require a lot of work, depending on how much identifying info your posts contain.

> What should i avoid?

Probably porn. But on a serious note, i think your question is "Could foolish technical questions impact my future employment?"

I don't think so. The digging you're afraid of is probably only done by high-security firms or governmental agencies.

FYI: By your profile i can tell you know a lot about the technical aspect  of aviation, are probably flying single-engine planes and are planning on publishing an e-book.

Comment: HAHAHA i really love this part of your answer: `Probably porn`.
Nice one!

Comment: Hey!  I'm proud of the fact that I started my career as a script kiddie and porn website maintainer (way before formal education).  Surprisingly enough, porn maintenance gives you exposure to enough malware to learn a lot about it.  **p0f** (passive fingerprinting tool, probably the first one) also argues that it initially collected data by running behind a porn website.  Just think of all the random traffic to analyse!  Porn is gold for infosec research.  Good answer nevertheless (+1)